# Grails Jsecurity plugin: Increase session timeout

Tags: grails, jsecurity

I am using Jsecurity plugin version 0.3 with grails 1.1. 
I need to increase the session timeout for users.

Any clue how i should go about this?

Comment: Got the answer from the Grails User list only "http://www.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-session-timeout-for-JSecurity--td23334017.html".
Just need to set session.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeoutSeconds)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to set the session timeout is installing the [WebXML Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) and set the session timeout in the web.xml.
Doing it this way you don't have to set it programmatically every time.

Comment: A good idea in theory, but it appears that the WebXML Plugin does not support changing the session timeout value.  It only allows adding filters, listeners and context parameters.  Should be easy enough to create a patch for this...

Comment: Currently it does not, but like you said adding it is no big deal. ;-) The other way is grails install-templates and manipulating the web.xml in a static mannor. If you are developing a plugin doWithWebDescriptor should be fine.